# Django SingleObjectMixin

Tags: django

I try to create simple SingleObjectMixin class, later i will use it with render_json_response() for providing AJAX data streaming. The main goal is basket for online store. So there is simple test class:

```
class Test(SingleObjectMixin):
    model = GoodsDescription
    slug_url_kwarg = 'test_id'
    slug_field = 'artikul' # pk field in 'GoodsDescription' table

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return render(request, 'temp_code.html', {'msg':self.object.name})
```

So the mistake is:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/test%3D5/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['alexbase',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'easy_thumbnails']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/test=5/
Exception Value: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: could we see urls.py please. Also I think you might be missing variable for id in `get`

Answer (score 3):

SingleObjectMixin is, well, a mixin. It's not a full view you can inherit from. You should use DetailView instead.

Answer (score 0):

URL conf string should be right:

```
url(r'^(?:test=(?P<test_id>\d+))/$', login_required(views.TestAJAXView), name='temp_code'),
```

Finally, i want to use class like this:

```
class TestAJAXView(JSONResponseMixin, SingleObjectMixin):
    model = GoodsDescription
    slug_url_kwarg = 'test_id'
    slug_field = 'artikul'
    json_dumps_kwargs = {"indent": 2}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        context_dict = {
            "category": self.object.category,
            "name": self.object.name
        }

        return self.render_json_response(context_dict)
```

But exception was raised, so i tried this:

```
class Test(SingleObjectMixin):
    model = GoodsDescription
    slug_url_kwarg = 'test_id'
    slug_field = 'artikul' # pk field in 'GoodsDescription' table

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return render(request, 'temp_code.html', {'msg':self.object.name})
```